# Can we just use the normal imageView for facebook photo?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/) says I should use:
FBProfilePictureView

Well, say I want to use regular imageView and then download the image URL. How would I get that imageURL?

Comment: a little bit of context would help. What tutorial are you talking about in the first place?

Comment: Added that. Okay, why is this not a real question because I got a really great answer that I really used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is taken directly from the `FBProfilePictureView` implementation. I kept only the basic things that allow you to download the profile picture and store it in a plain `UIImageView`.

```
#import "FBURLConnection.h"
#import "FBRequest.h"

//...

UIImageView * imageView = nil;
NSString * profileID = @"123456"; // the profile ID of the user you need to retrieve the image of;
FBURLConnectionHandler handler = ^(FBURLConnection *connection, NSError *error, NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data) {
     if (!error) {
         imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
     }
};

NSString *template = @"%@/%@/picture";     
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:template, 
                           FBGraphBasePath,
                           profileID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

[[FBURLConnection alloc] initWithURL:url
                   completionHandler:handler];
```

Still I think `FBProfilePictureView` is way more convenient than using a plain `UIImageView`. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because I already implement an ImageViewclass with caching and stuff.

Comment: Also I used your solution. I simply demand larger picture.

Comment: not to mention that users can also sign up using twitter :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get the profile picture of the user.

You can obtain the URL from Facebook OpenGraph User API call : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Look at `picture` attribute.

Comment: That's good. I am looking for something that uses IOS API.